# How to insert contents in declared JSX Component in React?

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I have been trying to create a JSXComponent with some functionalities inside that return a JSX element as a parent.

I want something like this:

```
<JSXComponent someProp="value">
  {({data, loading, error})} => (
     <div className="Parent">
        some html code...
      </div>
  )
</JSXComponent>
```

but on the output, it only returns the JSX element that returns in JSXComponent and not the contents of a function inside that JSXComponent

The result is like this:

```
<div className="JSXComponent">Some...</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a more complete example. It's not clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: I suspect the problem is inside `JSXComponent` but you haven't provided the defaults of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this using a higher order component.

```js
const hocWrapWithParent = ({ChildComponent}) => props => (
  <div className="Parent">
    <ChildComponent {...props} />
  </div>
);
const ChildComponent = ({someprop) => <div>some child with prop= {someprop}</div>;
const Wrapped = hocWrapWithParent({ChildComponent});

// <Wrapped someprop={'hello'} />
```